# Good WCF + JSON + JSONP screencast?

Tags: wcf, json, jsonp

Are there any good WCF + JSON + JSONP screencasts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't have JSONP, but it should answer your WCF + JSON requirement:

http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/The+EndPoint/Programming-JSON-with-WCF-in-NET-Framework-35

There is also http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee834511.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716898%28v=vs.90%29.aspx , if you have not already read those resources.